# does "linq where" not resolve properties?

Tags: c#

I have an IQueryable (PartHistories) that will return a set of objects. I have an enum called Phase that alters the query, like this (rc is a list):

```
            var query = this.PartHistories;
            if ( Phase.Repair == _Phase )
            {
                query = query.Where( ph => ph.RemovedInRepair == false );
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.Where( ph => ph.PartPhaseID != ( int )Phase.Repair );
            }
            rc.AddRange( query
                .ToList( ) );
```

This works.

Now, the object in question (PartHistory) has a property, PartPhase, which casts PartPhaseID as Phase.  This code, however, does NOT work (the change is in the Phase.Repair line):

```
            var query = this.PartHistories;
            if ( Phase.Repair == _Phase )
            {
                query = query.Where( ph => ph.RemovedInRepair == false );
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.Where( ph => ph.PartPhase != Phase.Repair );
            }
            rc.AddRange( query
                .ToList( ) );
```

At the AddRange, the exception is "the member 'PartPhase' is not supported.

Finally, the following code works, but in this case, the Where is the extension of List and (I think) applies after all the PartHistories have been collected:

```
          if( Phase.Repair == _Phase )
          {
              rc.AddRange( this.PartHistories.ToList( )
                  .Where( ph => ph.RemovedInRepair == false ) );
          }
          else
          {
              rc.AddRange( this.PartHistories.ToList( )
                  .Where( ph => ph.PartPhase != Phase.Repair ) );
```

Comment: You are correct in your last code sample that .where runs after .ToList(). I've never had problems with LINQ (to objects, which is IEnumerable rather than IQueryable) and properties. So the problem isn't jumping out at me, yet.

Comment: You might want to give us a little more detail about what the Phase and PartPhase classes look like.  Is PartPhase the same type as Repair?

Comment: Phase is just an enum; PartPhase is a property of PartHistory that returns an int cast as Phase.  So, yes, PartPhase is the same type as Repair; both are Phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is Linq to SQL, then yes, it does not support custom method calls.
It can translate expressions to SQL queries, but doesn't know what happens inside your property. So, custom methods and properties are not convertible to SQL.

If you could make an `Expression<Func<PartHistory, PartPhase>>`, which would do the same thing your property does (without calling custom methods), then it would work.

Comment: This sounds like a safe assumption

Comment: Thank you, Rotsor. This makes sense (that SQL would not understand my custom property).  I'll have to study up on how to make an Expression :) but for now, I guess I couldn't do much better than the code in the first example.